# CSS text-transform bug?

Tags: html, css, mysql

I'm not sure if I stumbled onto a bug or not in css or maybe the inputs..

I have a form that in css I am using on all my inputs

```
 text-transform: capitalize;
```

This works great on the Names I type in for example I type in the name 'peter' it shows up in the text box as 'Peter' which is awesome and working well..

My problem is that when I submit it to mysql database, it is submitted as 'peter'.

I don't know if this is by design or a bug, but if it is by design is there any suggestions on how to submit my desired result 'Peter'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design; CSS is a **front-end** language, and only manipulates the **client** (what the end-user sees). CSS is purely presentational, and does not affect the DOM, the server-side logic, nor the database. The server-side logic is that the name is still written in lowercase, and the value is still stored in the database in lowercase.

If you want to update the database value to be uppercase, you'll either have to submit the name **back** to your database with capitalisation (making use of PHP's **[`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)** function):

```
$string = 'peter';
echo $string; // 'peter' is written to the DOM
$capitalised = ucfirst($string);
echo $capitalised; // 'Peter' is written to the DOM
```

Or update the database directly with MySQL's **[`CONCAT`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)** function:

```
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(field, 1)), SUBSTRING(field, 2));
```

Comment: Or, since OP mentioned he is using a form, the capitalization can be done with JavaScript before form submit.

Comment: While you certainly *could* do this with JavaScript... it would be rather clunky (with something like `string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)`), in addition to the fact that you'd need to intercept the form submission just to do this. Also, if there were something like `strtolower()` server-side (for argument's sake) then it still wouldn't update the value on the server nor in the database.

Comment: I don't necessarily see that line of JS being any less clunky than the CONCAT function but alright

Comment: Thank you for the informative and easy to understand explanation.  Gives me a new direction. :)